# How can I populate an associative array with a variable name in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, dynamic, associative-array

I am trying to create an associative array with a variable name and having some trouble.  I am able to declare the array without any trouble, but when I try to populate it I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
ARR_NAME="tali"

makeArray () {
  name=${ARR_NAME}_$1
  echo name: $name
  declare -A $name  #this works fine
  ${name}=( [foo]=bar [baz]=quux [corge]=grault )  #this gives an error (see below)
}

makeArray dev
```

Here are the error messages I get:

```
./array_test.sh: line 135: syntax error near unexpected token `[one]=uno'
./array_test.sh: line 135: `  ${name}=( [one]=uno [two]=dos [three]=tres )'
```

Other things I have tried:

```
$name=( [one]=uno [two]=dos [three]=tres ) #same error message as above

declare -A $name=( [one]=uno [two]=dos [three]=tres ) 
# gives me the following error (basically the same as above):
./array_test.sh: line 134: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./array_test.sh: line 134: `  declare -A $name=( [one]=uno [two]=dos [three]=tres )'
```

I am new to bash and have been Googling anything and everything possible to figure this out, but no luck so far.  The closest answer I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767413/bash-use-a-variable-as-an-associative-array-name), but it didn't solve my problem.  I am using bash 4.3.

Note: this is just a practice script I am using to learn more about bash and associative arrays.  I am testing things out here to use in the actual script I am trying to write.

Comment: That linked answer should solve your problem. You need a nameref here. What about it didn't work? What did you try exactly? To clarify you won't be able to use the variable directly but you can give a local alias to the name in the variable.

Comment: `declare -A $name="( [one]=uno [two]=dos [three]=tres )"` will declare and define the array.

Answer (score 0):

> `declare -A $name="( [one]=uno [two]=dos [three]=tres )"` will declare and define the array.
>                       – rici

This is true, but missing the important **-g** option to make the array accessible outside of `makeArray`:

> The **-g** option forces
>                 variables  to  be  created or modified at the global scope, even
>                 when **declare** is executed in a shell function.

So it's

```
  declare -gA $name="( [foo]=bar [baz]=quux [corge]=grault )"
```